# Time Evolution of Heisenberg Operators $x$ and $x^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, time-evolution

In the Heisenberg picture, operators evolve according to

$$
\partial_t A = \frac{1}{i\hbar} [A,H].
$$

My question is, does the following relation hold?

$$
(X_H)^2 = (X^2)_H
$$

The system (Hamiltonian) in mind is the 1D harmonic oscillator,

$$
H = a^{\dagger}a + \frac 12 
$$

I would like to say that it does, but the Heisenberg equations of motion for $x^2$ and $p^2$ are very messy (and I believe nonlinear).

Comment: So to be very clear, is your question if $X_H^2=(X^2)_H$? The subscript $H$ denotes here operator in Heisenberg picture. If so, you should write down the definition of e.g. $X_H=\ldots$ in terms of $X$ (the position operator in the Schrödinger picture).

Comment: Yes, that is my question. Are you saying something like the relation $X_H = U^{\dagger} X_S U$. In which case it is clear that $(X_H)^2 =(X^2)_H$ ?

Comment: Indeed. Consider to write an answer yourself.

Answer (score 5):

The answer can be seen from going back to the definition of the Heisenberg operators in terms of the Schrodinger operators.

$$
X_H = U^{\dagger}X_S U
$$

Then, we have

$$
(X_H)^2 = U^{\dagger}X_S U U^{\dagger}X_S U = U^{\dagger}(X_S)^2 U = (X^2)_H
$$